# Nav bar is not scrolling to the correct tagged sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I implemented a scrolling page in a Fancybox script. The "nav" section is not working properly. The "nav" buttons seems to interact with the page under fancybox and not the fancybox itself.
Please take a look at it:

[Slider nav issue](http://thisischoo.co/index2/index.html)

To reproduce the issue: 
- click on first image below text on the landing page (Fancybox scripts shows up and you see a set of bicolor images)
- try to use nav on the right: when you click last button of the nav and click "esc" you will see that script is scrolling page under Fancybox (instead of the Fancybox bicolor images.)

Please help, I have been stuck on this issue for 3-4 days and have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle? It makes it easier to spot the problem